# Using not-found attribute of one-to-many mapping of hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

As per Hibernate docs for `one-to-many` xml mapping tag there is an attribute called as `not-found`

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-onetomany

The Doc says:

> not-found (optional - defaults to exception): specifies how cached
>   identifiers that reference missing rows will be handled. ignore will
>   treat a missing row as a null association.

What is the use of this attribute? I tried to create a mapping between Product and Parts with Product having a set of Parts with below mapping details:

```
<set name="parts" cascade="all">
    <key column="productSerialNumber" not-null="true" />
    <one-to-many class="Part" not-found="ignore"/>
</set>
```

Then I wrote my Java code as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Product prod = (Product) session.get(Product.class, 1);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println(prod);
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
    }
```

I was expecting null for my set which has Parts as I configured in my mapping file as `not-found="ignore"`. But I got the regular exception - `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`

Please help me in understanding what is the use of this attribute? What are cached identifiers here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The not-found has nothing to do with lazy loading. It's used to handle incoherences in your database.

Suppose you know nothing about good database practices, and have an `order_line` table containing an `order_id` column, supposed to reference the `order` it belongs to. And suppose that since you know nothing about good practices, you don't have a foreign key constraint on this column.

Deleting an order will thus be possible, even if the order has order lines referencing it. When loading such an OrderLine with Hibernate, Hibernate will load the Order and fail with an exception because it's supposed to exist, but doesn't.

Using `not-found=ignore` makes Hibernate ignore the order_id in the OrderLine, and will thus initialize the order field to null.

In a well-designed database, this attribute should never be used.